# Cache video (may more than 10m) directly using JavaScript on browser

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc, p2p

I am working out with WebRTC now, I want to share video stream peer to multi peers. So I think it will be better if I can cache some parts of video.

I have checked out Cache Web APIs, it seems no so helpful, what can I do to cache video (may more than 10m) directly using JavaScript on browser?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Blob` to store the data. Use `.slice()` to add chunks of data to existing `Blob`